# Texture painting on a model with a normal map

Tags: uv, normals, texture-painting

I have a lowpoly model with a normal map with a highpoly version of it and now want to have handpainted textures for it but cant find a way to do it efficiently since once you enter texture paint mode you cant see any of the normals.
**I was wondering if there was a way to have normals&lighting visible in texture paint mode.**

Only way i've found to be somewhat okay is in texture mode, so the UV's are visible, setting the mode to 'single image' (for some reason makes the normals show) and and painting on the image instead of the model since painting on it results in an error "Missing Textures detected!".

Comment: What version of Blender are you using at the moment with this? I have had really good feedback with Material draw mode using Cycles in 2.79, and even with Blender Render in 2.79 using material draw mode. In 2.8, it is much easier to see the results with Eevee, but there is a chance for crashes still depending on what is going on with the build.

Comment: Using blender 2.8, will try out if it works differently in 2.79!

Comment: Have you tried the Rendered view with the HDRI world background? I haven't had any problems with painting and getting decent feedback there. I cover painting in Blender on my youtube channel, and this was a test a while back in 2.8   https://youtu.be/jDEqH-TJHts?t=813

Comment: Looked trough the video and found that all i needed to do is disable the overlays, thank you so much!

Comment: I have the same problem with 2.8, but perhaps more nuanced.  I disabled the overlays as mentioned by @ErikasSuopys, and suddenly I saw the effects of my bump mapping while painting with the brush on the normals.  But then I clicked on something else, the miracle vanished, and it's broken again.

It seems like this part of 2.8 just isn't very stable yet (I'm using the 2019-01-09 version for Mac).  Guess I'll try a newer build.